# Assemble handlebars nested math helpers

Tags: node.js, handlebars.js, assemble

I was wondering whether there is a way to combine two **[Assemble Math helpers]**[1](http://assemble.io/helpers/helpers-math.html) in one operation.

For example:

- I want to do `{{multiply 12 a}}` and then
- do `{{round}}` on the resultant

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the new subexpressions in Handlebars you can do `{{round (multiply 12 a)}}`